# stop downloading when phone has low disk space

Tags: ios, http

I am downloading videos and pdfs from server. When my device memory is low say 50MB left , then while downloading my app crashes. How to check if the downloaded data will be more than memory space left in phone?

And if the data is more than space available , how to stop the downloading?

Is anyone aware of simple solution?

Comment: You're asking about disk space available, yes, not RAM space available.

Comment: I am asking about disk space.

Comment: @XYZ can you show us how you are downloading the files. Do you get a crash report or any memory warnings?

Comment: I do not have any crash reports Oliver. I am downloading the file using NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the available disk space before you start the request:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];
NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
```

When you get the `NSURLResponse` for the request you are making it should (hopefully) have a content size header so you know how much data to expect. If the amount of data is too high you can `cancel` the request (assuming you're using `NSURLConnection` with a delegate) and alert the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wain. I can get the disk space from your answer but my response data header field does not show me anything like content-length. Also I have tried long long expectedData = [httpResponse expectedContentLength]; , but this also returns -1.

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the server to send the content length? If not, there isn't much you can do other than take the average size and hard code it...

Comment: NO ,I can not change the server.

Comment: Then you should probably check that a certain amount of space is available. Decide that amount of space based on the files you usually download.